# How to add grids plugin dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to add grids plugin dynamically.

I have grid and I want toload `rowExpander` dynamically. So here is what i am trying to add. But my grid is not loading with expander. Can any body load with this.

```
beforerender: function(me,eOpts){

    var Details= [{Semester: 1,Maths: 75,Science: 50,Total: 150,Marks: [{    Mat: 50,    Sci: 25,    Exam: "Sem11"}, {    Mat: 25,    Sci: 25,    Exam: "Sem12"}]
        }, {Semester: 2,Maths: 75,Science: 50,Total: 150,Marks: [{    Mat: 50,    Sci: 25,    Exam: "Sem21"}, {    Mat: 25,    Sci: 25,    Exam: "Sem22"}]
        }];

        if(me.plugins.length === 0){
            var someGrid = {
                ptype: 'rowexpandergrid',
                gridConfig: [{
                    store:  Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                        storeId:'student',
                        fields:['productid', 'productName', 'qty'],
                        data:[],
                    }),
                    columns: [{ text: "Maths", dataIndex: 'Mat' },{ text: "Science", dataIndex: 'Sci' }],
                    columnLines: false,
                    border: true,
                    autoWidth: true,
                    autoHeight: true,
                    frame: false,
                    header: false,
                    plugins:[]
                }]
            };
            someGrid["gridConfig"][0].store.load(Details);
            me.plugins.push(someGrid); 
        }
    }
```

On before render method I am adding the plugins. Can anybody help me to correct my code.

Answer (score 1):

In your `beforeRender` method you are adding `me.plugins.push(someGrid);` remove that line and instead of that add plugin to grid.

replace that line with this. It will work.

`me.addPlugin(someGrid)`

Comment: I am getting some cls issue on this.